# Gotestsum warning about unable to stat an existing test file

Tags: vim

I'm trying to use gotestsum with the watch flag but I always get a warning like below:

```
WARN failed to stat path/to/pkg/Somefile_test.go~: stat path/to/pkg/Somefile_test.go~: no such file or directory
```

The tests pass (or fail) correctly (the message is always printed after "Done [n] tests ..."), but I seem to always have a single warning from stat about a file or directory that doesn't exist. I've tried using the path of the package relative to the current directory and just the package name as well as '-- ./...' but all seem to result in this warning. Oddly there is only one warning for a single missing test file even if I have multiple test files, and only when using the --watch flag. It also is only issued when a file is saved, pressing 'r' or 'a' inside the terminal emulator window doesn't cause the warning to be issued. There must be something simple I'm missing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, many editors create a backup of the file currently edited, and give the backup file the name of the original file plus a tilde. This file is generally removed once the file is saved.

If you happen to be using vim, you can just add the following to your .vimrc

```
set nobackup
```

So it would make sense that when you save, it gets a list of files, but by the time it tries to stat, the backup (tilde) version no longer exists.

Comment: To get the best of both worlds, you may consider to `:set backupdir` to some absolute path on your machine. Vim will create backup files there and not clutter your local directory.